# Cannot infer type when checking all of a database row's fields before parsing them into a struct

Tags: rust

I made a function to check all of the row's fields before parsing them into a struct:

```rust
pub fn check_result_field<'a>(row: &Vec<postgres::Row>) -> ErrorObject {
    for r in row {
        for i in 0..row.len() {
            match r.try_get(i) {
                Ok(result) => {
                    return ErrorObject::default();
                }
                Err(err) => {
                    return ErrorObject::new("postgres".to_string(), err.to_string());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ErrorObject::default();
}
```

But I always get an error:

```
     Ok(result) => {
   |                    ^^^^^^ cannot infer type
```

I would like to use that function like this:

```rust
let mut roles: Vec<RoleEntity> = Vec::new();
match data {
    Ok(result) => {
        let err = connection::check_result_field(&result);
        if err.message != "" {
            return (roles, err);
        }
        for row in result {
            let role = RoleEntity {
                id: row.get(0),
                role: row.get(1),
                created_at: row.get(2),
                updated_at: row.get(3),
                deleted_at: row.get(4),
            };
            roles.push(role)
        }
    }
    Err(err) => return (roles, Error::new("postgres".to_string(), err.to_string())),
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [postgres](https://crates.io/crates/postgres) crate. The documentation for [`try_get`](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.17.2/postgres/row/struct.Row.html#method.try_get) shows that it is a generic function that depends on the type you expect the field to have, so you need to specify this type one way or another.

Instead of having a `check_result_field` function, you should use `try_get` directly along with the `?` operator to handle errors. Something like:

```
let mut roles: Vec<RoleEntity> = Vec::new();
match data {
    Ok(result) => {
        for row in result {
            let role = RoleEntity {
                id: row.try_get(0)?,
                role: row.try_get(1)?,
                created_at: row.try_get(2)?,
                updated_at: row.try_get(3)?,
                deleted_at: row.try_get(4)?,
            };
            roles.push(role)
        }
    }
    Err(err) => return Err(err),
}
```

Note: this will probably require changes to the code you haven't shown us, especially for error handling, but it is impossible to help here without a true [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).